# Installing laravel dusk on 5.5.34

Tags: laravel

I have laravel  5.5.34

I'm trying to install dusk. `composer require --dev laravel/dusk`
I get the following errors...

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.34, required as 5.6.*) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.34] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - laravel-admin-ext/helpers dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel-admin-ext/helpers dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - laravel-admin-ext/helpers dev-master requires laravel/framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.5.x-dev, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.4, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for laravel-admin-ext/helpers dev-master -> satisfiable by laravel-admin-ext/helpers[dev-master].
```

Why this? `The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.34, required as 5.6.*)`

Isn't dusk introduced in laravel 5.4?

**UPDATE Here is composer.json**
https://pastebin.com/ihfW3LeY

Comment: Why are you using `laravel/framework: 5.6.*` in your composer file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an older tag with Laravel 5.5 support

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^2.0
```

Comment: reproduced the original issue (https://imgur.com/a/DAOxN) in a fresh install, but it worked with the tag `^2.0` (https://imgur.com/a/e5D6G)

Comment: I think that another package is locking our requirements like `laravel-admin-ext/helpers`. Can you [edit] your question with your `composer.json` file, please?