# installing Dusk on laravel V6.14.0

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, installation, laravel-dusk

I have Laravel 6.14 and when I run the `composer require --dev laravel/dusk` command i get the following error (summarized, because I can't post more than 30000 characters)

```
Using version ^5.10 for laravel/dusk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.14.0, required as ^5.2) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25


    - Installation request for laravel/dusk ^5.10 -> satisfiable by laravel/dusk[v5.10.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker (locked at v2.2.0, required as ^2.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v2.2.0].
    - Installation request for laravel/ui (locked at v1.1.2, required as ^1.1) -> satisfiable by laravel/ui[v1.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.3.x-dev
    - laravel/dusk v5.10.0 requires illuminate/support ~5.7.0|~5.8.0|^6.0|^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, 
v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/support[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, 7.x-dev, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, 
v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.2.x-dev, v6.14.0].
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^5.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.2.0, v5.2.0-beta1, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, v5.2.19, v5.2.2, v5.2.20, v5.2.21, v5.2.22, v5.2.23, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.29, v5.2.3, v5.2.30, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9, v5.3.0, v5.3.0-RC1, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, v5.3.8, v5.3.9, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.5.45, v5.5.46, 
v5.5.47, v5.5.48, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I already tried installing an older version as suggested by this post: [Installing laravel dusk on 5.5.34](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815952/installing-laravel-dusk-on-5-5-34)

Other commands I've tried

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^2.0
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^2.0" 
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^4.0  
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:"^4.0" 
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:5.0
```

All of them give me the same error. So how do I get Dusk installed into my project?

### Update

This is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^5.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

My composer show result

```
doctrine/inflector                    1.3.1     Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                 1.3.0     A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                        1.2.0     PHP Doctrine Lexer parser library that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
dragonmantank/cron-expression         v2.3.0    CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a CRON expression is due
egulias/email-validator               2.1.15    A library for validating emails against several RFCs
facade/flare-client-php               1.3.1     Send PHP errors to Flare
facade/ignition                       1.16.0    A beautiful error page for Laravel applications.
facade/ignition-contracts             1.0.0     Solution contracts for Ignition
fideloper/proxy                       4.2.2     Set trusted proxies for Laravel
filp/whoops                           2.7.1     php error handling for cool kids
fzaninotto/faker                      v1.9.1    Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
hamcrest/hamcrest-php                 v2.0.0    This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
jakub-onderka/php-console-color       v0.2
jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.4      Highlight PHP code in terminal
laravel/framework                     v6.14.0   The Laravel Framework.
laravel/tinker                        v2.2.0    Powerful REPL for the Laravel framework.
laravel/ui                            v1.1.2    Laravel UI utilities and presets.
league/commonmark                     1.2.2     PHP Markdown parser based on the CommonMark spec
league/commonmark-ext-table           v2.1.0    Table extension for league/commonmark
league/flysystem                      1.0.64    Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
mockery/mockery                       1.3.1     Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework
monolog/monolog                       2.0.2     Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
myclabs/deep-copy                     1.9.5     Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nesbot/carbon                         2.29.1    An API extension for DateTime that supports 281 different languages.
nikic/php-parser                      v4.3.0    A PHP parser written in PHP
nunomaduro/collision                  v3.0.1    Cli error handling for console/command-line PHP applications.
opis/closure                          3.5.1     A library that can be used to serialize closures (anonymous functions) and arbitrary objects.
paragonie/random_compat               v9.99.99  PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phar-io/manifest                      1.0.3     Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                       2.0.1     Library for handling version information and constraints
phpdocumentor/reflection-common       2.0.0     Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     4.3.4     With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise retrieve ...   
phpdocumentor/type-resolver           1.0.1     A PSR-5 based resolver of Class names, Types and Structural Element Names
phpoption/phpoption                   1.7.2     Option Type for PHP
phpspec/prophecy                      v1.10.2   Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage             7.0.10    Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage informa...   
phpunit/php-file-iterator             2.0.2     FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template             1.2.1     Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                     2.1.2     Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream              3.1.1     Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                       8.5.2     The PHP Unit Testing framework.
psr/container                         1.0.0     Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/log                               1.1.2     Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                      1.0.1     Common interfaces for simple caching
psy/psysh                             v0.9.12   An interactive shell for modern PHP.
ramsey/uuid                           3.9.2     Formerly rhumsaa/uuid. A PHP 5.4+ library for generating RFC 4122 version 1, 3, 4, and 5 universally un...   
scrivo/highlight.php                  v9.18.1.0 Server side syntax highlighter that supports 185 languages. It's a PHP port of highlight.js
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup    1.0.1     Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                  3.0.2     Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                        3.0.2     Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                 4.2.3     Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                    3.1.2     Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                3.0.0     Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator           3.0.3     Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/object-reflector            1.1.1     Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ones
sebastian/recursion-context           3.0.0     Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations         2.0.1     Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/type                        1.1.3     Collection of value objects that represent the types of the PHP type system
sebastian/version                     2.0.1     Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
swiftmailer/swiftmailer               v6.2.3    Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/console                       v4.4.4    Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                  v4.4.4    Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                         v4.4.4    Symfony Debug Component
symfony/error-handler                 v4.4.4    Symfony ErrorHandler Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v4.4.4    Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts    v1.1.7    Generic abstractions related to dispatching event
symfony/finder                        v4.4.4    Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation               v4.4.4    Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v4.4.4    Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/mime                          v4.4.4    A library to manipulate MIME messages
symfony/polyfill-ctype                v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill for ctype functions
symfony/polyfill-iconv                v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill for the Iconv extension
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn             v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill for intl's idn_to_ascii and idn_to_utf8 functions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring             v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php72                v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php73                v1.13.1   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.3+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/process                       v4.4.4    Symfony Process Component
symfony/routing                       v4.4.4    Symfony Routing Component
symfony/service-contracts             v1.1.8    Generic abstractions related to writing services
symfony/translation                   v4.4.4    Symfony Translation Component
symfony/translation-contracts         v1.1.7    Generic abstractions related to translation
symfony/var-dumper                    v4.4.4    Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
theseer/tokenizer                     1.1.3     A small library for converting tokenized PHP source code into XML and potentially other formats
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles     2.2.2     CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files into HTML-pages/files with in...   
vlucas/phpdotenv                      v3.6.0    Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` automagically.
webmozart/assert                      1.6.0     Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
```

Comment: Please post your `composer.json` file and the result of `composer show`.

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir I've posted them in my question under update

Comment: I don't understand how you can have different major versions of `laravel/framework` (`^5.2` vs. `6.14.0`), that shouldn't be possible. Does a command like `composer update` work?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir I've changed the "laravel/framework": "^5.2" to "laravel/framework": "^6.2" and everything seems to work now. I have no idea why it was set to ^5.2. I have never manually touched this file before, but thank you for helping me. If you post an answer saying the laravel/framework version in my composer.json is wrong, I'll gladly accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the version of `laravel/framework` in `composer.json` (back) to `^6.2`:

```
"laravel/framework": "^6.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

The package you required is recommended to be placed in require-dev (because it is tagged as "testing") but you did not use --dev

**composer install --dev**

then use particular version for your project

**composer require laravel/dusk:^6.1 or composer require laravel/dusk:***

Comment: When using code in a post, please surround the code in backticks (\`\`\`). This will format it as code. (More info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)